# Android buttons turn black when pressed (if supports-screens in in the AndroidManifest.xml)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-button

I've built a test app to demonstrate the problem.

I have an Android app which has a couple of buttons with semi-transparent gradient background.

The problem is - when the button is pressed, the space under the button turns black (screenshot provided).

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

After a long time of searching for the cause i've found, that the problem is caused by this entry in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

If i delete it, everything is ok. Anyone have any thoughts on this one?

P.S 
I should mention, that this may be device specific, since i have a Samsung Galaxy S phone (i9000) but with android 4.3 flashed to it (don't judge me on that :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably to do with the line

```
android:anyDensity="false"
```

According to the official documentation on supports-screens found at [Supports Screens Element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html),

"you should not set it "false" unless you're absolutely certain that it's necessary for your application to work."

It then references the documentation on Supporting multiple screens which says that if it is false, the drawing operations can have unexpected behaviour. See [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations), point 2 on Auto-scaling of pixel dimensions and coordinates.

Hopefully this provides an explanation.